# How to consolidate tables in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need to consolidate 2 sheets in the same Google Sheets file. Both have a column in common, which I can use to relate them. However, it is possible that in one of the files the column has values that are not present in the 2nd sheet, which is correct. When I consolidate both sheets, I need to see all the values from the 1st sheet, showing blanks in the other columns of the 2nd file. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I created an example in this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aBrHhCKoyoV7e_O8MUy4rL9aC922Xp8yiqH5gv_gpLM/edit?usp=sharing

I have 2 sheets in the same file and I want to create a 3rd sheet with a consolidated sheet, showing all the epics from the 1st sheet. Note that not all epics are present in the 2nd sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **A1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Refined scope'!C:C, Epics!A:D, {1,2,3,4}, 0)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0); 
 FILTER(Epics!A:D, NOT(COUNTIF('Refined scope'!C1:C, Epics!A1:A)))})
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **E1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA('Refined scope'!A:E)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. You helped me a lot!